# Ball withdrawn from a box. Put the other color back. Then take out another ball.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Question: A box contains 3 white and 4 black balls. We draw a ball, if it is white we remove the obtained ball and add one black ball to the box, if it is black we remove the obtained ball and add one white ball to the box. After that we draw one more ball.

a) Given that the second ball is black, find the probability that the first ball was white.

b) Find the probability that the second ball is white.

Attempt:

a) The given that is being the second ball is black doesn't change the outcome of the first one. So it is 3/7.

b) I dont know how to approach this one. Should I try to solve it with cases. 
Case 1, first ball is white, then a white ball is taken out 2/7. 
Case 2, first ball is black, a white ball is added, 4/7. Then it is  6/7? 
Or if I am doing this in a conditional way, $P(w_2|w_1)=(\frac{P(w_1\cap w_2)}{P(w1)})$ Which doesn't makes sense to me because what is the intersection of that? The number of white balls? What am I missing out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: for b) I thought about something else. $w_1$ then $w_2$ is $3/7*2/7$ and $b_1$ then $w_2$ is $4/7*4/7$. Then we add these cases to each other.

Comment: Your answer for b) given in the comment is correct.It is $\frac{22}{49}$

Comment: what about a), does given that the second ball is black conditions the probability that the first ball is white?

Comment: Answer to question a) is $\frac59$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a)
Say x is the first pull and y is the second in the probability function P(x,y):
$$P(x=W,y=B) = \frac{3}{7} \times \frac{5}{7}=\frac{15}{49}$$
$$P(x=B,y=B) = \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{3}{7}=\frac{12}{49}$$
$$P(x=W|y=B) = \frac{P(x=W,y=B)}{P(x=W,y=B)+P(x=B,y=B)}=\frac{5}{9}$$
You can't discount the condition you are given just because it occurs second.

b)
$$P(x=W,y=W) = \frac{3}{7} \times \frac{2}{7}=\frac{6}{49}$$
$$P(x=B,y=W) = \frac{4}{7} \times \frac{4}{7}=\frac{16}{49}$$
$$P(y=W) = P(x=W,y=W) + P(x=B,y=W) = \frac{22}{49}$$

Comment: How do we know that P(W|B)= P(W,B)/P(W,B)+P(B,B)? Where's the intersection of first white then black?

Comment: the denominator is all trials where the second pull is black, which of course contains white followed by black.

Comment: ahh I get it now, thank you!